# Is there any concrete connection between a regular transition matrix and aperiodicty and irreducibility of a finite-state Markov Process?

Tags: markov-process, transition-matrix

The transition matrix 
*T* = \begin{bmatrix} 3/4 &1/4 \\ 1 &0 \end{bmatrix}

is clearly a regular transition matrix but the chain itself is not aperiodic (although it is irreducible), right?

(My reasoning behind its non-aperiodicity is that while *state 1* is aperiodic, *state 2* is not since it has a period of 2.)

In a standard linear algebra text, I read that a Markov Process has a unique stationary distribution iff the transition matrix is regular. (The above transition matrix being regular indeed has a unique stationary distribution [4/5  1/5].)

However, I read in a Cover's & Thomas' *Elements of Information Theory* that: if the Markov Process is aperiodic and irreducible, then it has a stationary distribution that is unique. However, as I have deduced above the matrix *T* is clearly not aperiodic.

These two ways of describing a finite-state transition matrix are, therefore, quite confusing to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Many Thanks!

Comment: State $2$ is also aperiodic. Consider that $\mathbb P(X_2=2\mid X_0=2)$ and $\mathbb P(X_3=2\mid X_0=2)$ are both positive.

Comment: Oh yes! you are absolutely right. I think I got messed up in my understanding of aperiodicity of a chain. But, one last question: Could you please clarify if a Markov Process which has a regular transition matrix is also aperiodic and irreducible always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Markov chain with a regular transition matrix is always irreducible and aperiodic.

Let $M$ denote the transition matrix. So there exists $n$ such that $M^n$ has all positive entries. Then clearly it is possible to get from any state to any other state, so the chain is irreducible. Furthermore, this implies $P(X_n = i \mid X_0=i)>0$ for all $i$. Now if $M^n$ has all positive entries, then so does $M^{n+1}$, and so we also have $P(X_{n+1}=i \mid X_0=i)>0$ for all $i$. Since $\gcd(n,n+1)=1$, this implies all states are aperiodic.